# Unable to Save Excel File - Win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am using Python to open an Excel file (xlsxwriter used to create the Excel File), then add Pivot Table, Chart and Slicers and then I need to Save and Close it. I can get everything done except the Save part. I want Excel to Save file with the same name and same format without even asking me to confirm or something like that...

```
import win32com.client as win32
from pathlib import Path

win32c = win32.constants

f_path = Path.cwd()
f_name = "filename.xlsx"

filename = f_path / f_name

# Create Excel Object

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

# Excel Can be Visible or Not + Display Alerts or Not

excel.Visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = False

# Initiate the workbook

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)

#HERE IS THE CODE TO ADD PIVOT TABLE, CHART AND SLICERS - WORKS AS EXPECTED WITHOUT ERRORS   

# Save Workbook

wb.Close(SaveChanges = 1)

# Close Excel

excel.Application.Quit()
```

If I use `wb.Close(SaveChanges = 1)`, it doesn't just save the file, it opens SaveAs window and suggests me to save SAME format with the different weird name and it doesn't even let me to overwrite (use same name) existing file. I have to select different name, then delete previous file, then rename new file to match the original filename and then I still need manually close the Excel.

[image]

If I use `wb.Save()` it does exactly the same thing.

If I use `wb.SaveAs(str(filename), win32c.xlWorkbookDefault)` it does again the same

`wb.SaveAs(Filename = str(filename))` - Same

`wb.SaveAs(str(filename), FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)` - Same

Answer (score 0):

After you make changes to file.
Use `time.sleep(5) wb.Save() excel.Quit()`
It took me an hour, to understand, that `wb.Close()` is closing file, before it succeeds to save - so do not use `wb.Close()`.